# Change attribute for object and return the object in one line

Tags: python

Is is possible to rewrite this code:

```
def function(obj):
    obj.attrib = 8
    return obj
```

So the set of the attribute and the return line appears in only one line? Something like:

```
def function(obj):
    return obj.attrib = 8 # of course, this does not work
```

Comment: Well, Python still has `;` so `obj.attrib = 8; return obj` should do that. But I guess, you are looking for a trick. I don't think there is one.

Comment: Python isn't the best language to *code golf*. There's no advantage to have this in one line instead of more readable two lines.

Comment: You don't even need to return anything, check my answer below!

Answer (score 4):

You could do this:

```
def function(obj):
    return setattr(obj, 'attrib', 8) or obj
```

This works because built-in function [`setattr`](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/setattr) returns None.

Comment: Anyone reading this in the future will have to puzzle over what `setattr` may be returning here, since to anyone sensible this reads as "return whatever `setattr` returns or fall back to `obj`"…

Comment: I changed the answer a few minutes after posting it to include a reference to `setattr` function. And yes, this is a misuse of Python, a hack, and an exploit of a side-effect, but it is an answer to the given question.

Comment: I mean, if you use this in production code, anyone coming after you would be puzzling over this. So you'd need to include a comment line linking to this answer or the documentation to make the code really understandable, at which point you have two lines again… ;-)

Comment: I agree. And if the question was _"Should I do this in a single line like this?"_ I would answer _"No."_ :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return the object, the object you pass in the argument to the function will have the `attrib` set and you can refer it directly from the caller code.

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, attrib):
        self.attrib = attrib

def function(obj):
    obj.attrib = 8

obj = A(5)
#This line prints 5
print(obj.attrib)
#5
function(obj)
#This line prints 8
print(obj.attrib)
#8
```

Or a better approach might be:

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, attrib):
        self.attrib = attrib

    def function(self, attrib):
        self.attrib = attrib

obj = A(5)
print(obj.attrib)
#5
obj.function(8)
print(obj.attrib)
#8
```

Comment: While this represents best practice, it does not answer the question.

Comment: It obviates the need of `return` from `function`, invalidating the intent of the question!